# Can't grab a day from datetime in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, slim-lang

Basically, what work in rails console doesn't seem to work in my view - I have a workshop model with column "start_date" of datetime type. 
I have created an object of this kind and when I enter rails console

```
  Workshop.find(<id>).start_date.day
```

returns specific day as expected (e.g. '21' in case of datetime 'Fri, 21 Apr 2017 17:00:00 UTC +00:00').

However, in my view I am not able to use 'day' method. I'm using Slim gem and this code in my show view for workshop:

```
p= workshop.start_date.day
```

results in this error: *undefined method `day' for nil:NilClass*

But code

```
p= workshop.start_date
```

displays the whole date properly and code

```
p= workshop.start_date.class
```

displays that the class of the object is: ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

What is happening, why do Rails say that the class is nil, how to make it work?

Comment: I guess there is some record which has the start_date attribute 'nil'. That is the reason for the error. Can you please put a condition in the view and check 'workshop.start_date.day if workshop.start_date' May be this will help you catch such errors.

Comment: I'm retarded - thanks, that was exactly it. I was developing field after field and haven't turned on the validation for this one yet so there was one object with this field set to nil - it won't be a case in the future.

Comment: No worries. This happens while coding. Cheers for happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following in views,

```
p= workshop.start_date.day if workshop.start_date
```

I guess some record has the start_date attribute nil and that is the reason the views throw error.

Comment: That's my guess as well. I'd add that using the safe navigator introduced in Ruby 2.3 is a more elegant way to handle this in a view: `p = workshop&.start_date&.day`.


Read more about it here: http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

Comment: Cool. That is also a best way. Hope that works well. Cheers.